# Detecting transparency in an image

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I need to determine whether a png image contains any transparency - what would be the most efficient code to achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Convert the PNG image to a pixelbuffer and use *vimage* to calculate the histograms of the color distributions. Then check the alpha channel histogram. *vimage* is much faster than going through the pixels one by one.

```
CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;

vImagePixelCount histogramA[256];
vImagePixelCount histogramR[256];
vImagePixelCount histogramG[256];
vImagePixelCount histogramB[256];
vImagePixelCount *histogram[4];
histogram[0] = histogramA;
histogram[1] = histogramR;
histogram[2] = histogramG;
histogram[3] = histogramB;
vImage_Buffer vbuff;
vbuff.height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pxbuffer);
vbuff.width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pxbuffer);
vbuff.rowBytes = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pxbuffer);

vbuff.data = pxbuffer;
vImage_Error err = vImageHistogramCalculation_ARGB8888 (&vbuff, histogram, 0);
if (err != kvImageNoError) NSLog(@"%ld", err);

int trans = 255 // How little transparency you want to include
BOOL transparent = NO;
for(int i=0; i<trans; i++){
   if(histogram[0][i]>0) transparent = YES;
}
```

*vimage* assumes that the colors are ordered ARGB in the buffer. If you have something else, e.g. BGRA, you just check histogram[3][i] instead.

Even faster is probably to first split the buffer into four planar buffers using vImageConvert_ARGB8888toPlanar8 and then just do the histogram calculation on the alfa buffer using vImageHistogramCalculation_Planar8.

You can open the PNG image as a CGImage and use vImageBuffer_initWithCGImage to convert it directly to a *vimage* buffer (see session 703 at [WWDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Worldwide_Developers_Conference) 2014).

Finally, an alternative would be to use Core Image to calculate the histogram.

Comment: I think the i variable should be initialised to 0, in order to handle pixels that are fully transparent (with an alpha value == 0)